# Wacom Intuos 3 with Inkscape 0.47

Tags: 10.04, input-devices, wacom, graphics-tablet, inkscape

How do you set up Inkscape 0.47 to work with Wacom Intuos 3?
In particular, I'd like to get pressure-sensitivity to work on Inkscape. I have "Use pressure-sensitive tablet" checked under the Inkscape Preferences, but it doesn't seem to be working. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind.

You can take a look at this for the solution. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom#Inkscape